# Page caching Is not working

Tags: htaccess, cache

This is my htaccess file.I also embedded webcaching code inside it.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.decodinghinduism.in
RewriteRule (.*) http://decodinghinduism.in/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
</IfModule>
```

**`Webcaching code`**

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>

deny from **.**.
```

But Webcaching is not working ,[Analytical result is here](http://www.site-analyzer.com/en/report/http://decodinghinduism.in/#report-page-2).Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check with a different tool, looks like caching is actually working.

[Result from Google Page Speed insights](http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http://decodinghinduism.in/&tab=mobile)

You can also check with the [Page speed browser extension](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights_extensions) and [Yahoo's Yslow Extension](http://yslow.org/)